# Is there Visual Studio 10 Add-On to support auto generate C++ declaration and implementation code?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

guys,
Is there a VS2010 VC++ add-on to auto generate C++ class method declaration code in header file and implementation code in cpp file when I am trying to add a new method into an existing class?

Too many add-on. Maybe there is, but I don't know which one.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Assist X from [Whole Tomato](http://www.wholetomato.com/) has an "Add Member" as well as "Create Implementation" and "Create Declaration" functions. It can also move implementation to source amongst other things. So far this has been the best (and only) c++ plug-in I use. Further, it's Intellisense feature is much better than Visual Studio's built in one.
Unfortunately it's not free, but well worth it.

Comment: "it's intellisense feature is much better" ... can you back up this claim for VS2010 as well? (I'm just asking because out-of-the-box Intellisense is supposed to have improved a lot in VS2010.)

Comment: @Martin - It's more based on personal experience: VS "feels" way more responsive with Visual Assist. The functionality itself in VS has improved a lot in 2010, but the IDE feels very sluggish at times when that functionality is enabled, (especially when the databases are being built) and this bothered me especially when working on my laptop. On the high-end servers at work, with 12GB of RAM and multiple cores, it's less of an issue. Things improved somewhat after VS SP1, but I still prefer to use Visual Assist. If in doubt, turn off the VS intellisense engine, and try out the trial version.

Comment: @Martin: ran out of space there :P so to conclude: I can't back it up. VS2010 has improved tremendously over previous versions, but when given the choice I still prefer VAX over the built-in functionality. Unfortunately I don't have licences on all my machines, and in that case: *if* the machine is "good" enough, the built-in functionality is definitely useful.

Comment: Thanks for the details. I just wanted to make sure you're actually using it with VS2010 and not VS2008 or somesuch ;-)